# Ext js 4 boxselect shows multiselect data when editing the form

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Is there any methods to load the multiselected data on Boxselect xtype while editing the form in EXTJS 4
I am using

```
Ext.getCmp('boxselect id').setValue(5,6,7,10).
```

The above code is working when i give the single value to set value,but my condtion is to load multiple selected data when editing the form,because the boxselect is of multiselect type.

```
{
                                xtype : 'boxselect',
                                store : 'store',
                                name: 'attributes',
                                id: 'attributes',
                                displayField: 'name',
                                valueField: 'abbr',
                                multiSelect : true,
                                fieldLabel: 'Attribute',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                editable: true,
                                allowQueryAll : false,
                                forceSelection : true,
                                typeAhead: true,
                                triggerAction: 'all',
                                delimiter : ','
                            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Ext.getCmp('boxselect id').setValue([5,6,7,10]).
Make sure array